# Multiprocessing Pool with timings or Process with maximum cores?

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, pool

I do not know if I understand multiprocessing correctly but for what I need it is basically doing thousands of small requests to a server. To simplify that I started testing out a little bit with just having a list of tasks and making it calculate on each item in that list some small thing.
The issue with requests to servers are that you do not want to spam the server or get potentially black listed.
For this i need a timing, which fits perfectly with `multiprocessing.Process()`.
On the other hand whenever I use that with multiple 1000 processess it sometimes crashes, or at least crashes all other running programs.
For this I would need a Pool of Processes, wheer `mulitprocessing.Pool()` fits perfectly.

Am I missing something or is there a way for me to get best of both worlds?

Here some example code I am trying out for this:

```
import time
import multiprocessing

def foo(para):
    # do something very lightweight 
    print(para*2)

parameters = [] # a long populated list of values, can be up to 100k processes long

# test Process
for para in parameters:
    Process(target=foo, args=(para)).start()
    time.sleep(0.06) # my rate limit in this case

# test Pool
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    pool.starmap(target=foo, zip(parameters))
```

The issue I am facing is that I am either getting banned from requesting or that I crash my device. Any help would be greatly appreciated. And please enlighten me if I am missing something about multiprocessing. I am new to this.

Comment: What does "banned from requesting" have to do with the code you've shown? My guess is that you're trying to implement some kind of web crawler. That's a different matter altogether. As a general rule (there will always be exceptions) use multiprocessing for CPU-intensive work and multithreading for I/O based operations (including web requests).

Comment: If you are rate-limited to one request every 60ms, you hardly need any multiprocessing, even straight Python should be able to do that, so I don't see what multiprocessing is buying you.

Comment: @LancelotduLac oh thank you. I actually did not know that. I will read a little bit more into multithreading. Is that also possible with the pythons multiprocessing or some other import?

Comment: @MarkSetchell just an example. Can be a lot faster than that, i just tried to make it simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Pathos is a great library to do that (pip install pathos) using the processingPool(processlimit) method. Here is an example on how u could use a pool :

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
import time

start = time.perf_counter()

def function(arg):
    arg = arg + 5
    time.sleep(1)
    return arg

def main():
    argumentlist = [20, 136, 176, 228, 403, 433, 491, 543, 559, 575, 724, 760, 776, 792, 808, 860, 1035, 1051, 1067, 1083, 1177, 1193]

    pool = Pool(4) #the argument here is the number of processes you limit your pool to
    results = pool.map(function, argumentlist)
    for result in results:
        print(result)

    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"Finished in {round(end-start, 2)} second(s)")
```

That was concerning limiting the number of processes runing at a time. But in your case you would have to check the maximum number of request/hour authorised by the api you are using, create a break before that limit and continue were you left off after an amount of time.

If Retrieving the information requested takes a lot of time then multiprocessing isn't the right choice. You need to use multithreading.

Here is the tutorial that taught me how to use multithreading. I think you will be able to learn what you want to know from it

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEEhzQoKtQU